# How to ask confirmation before deletion with a table

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a tableview and when the user swipes I want to ask them if they are sure they want to delete it.

What I've tried is in my DataSource class, in the CommitEditingStyle, I check for the UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete and if that's what happening, then I want to present a UIAlertView (if the user has selected this preference). I can Show the AlertView without a problem, and I include an instance of the AlertViewDelegate class I created, but if I click either the Cancel or OK buttons, everything crashes. I thought maybe I needed to invoke this on the MainThread, so I've tried that, but no success there.

The code I have when the OK button is clicked is simple, it calls the DeleteStuff method I have on the datasource class (I pass a reference to the datasource), which allows for the deleted row to fade and everything to happen as if their preference was no confirmations to be presented.

The delete is invoked by the user swiping the row of the table and then clicking the standard delete button.

I figure there's something key that I'm missing.

Comment: You should be using a UIActionSheet for confirming a dangerous action, not a UIAlert. Please see Apple's Human Interface Guidelines. See also this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598043/how-to-do-delete-confirmation-on-ipad-according-to-the-human-interface-guidelines

Comment: @occulus, sadly I never received a satisfactory answer to that question.

Comment: what's the error? Post the actual delete code that you have...

Comment: The error was a NullReference officially, but it pointed to the Main.cs. I've taken the advice to flip it to an ActionSheet and it works great. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code it's almost impossible to tell what's wrong. However, for your information, you may want do this stuff using an `UIActionSheet` instead of an `UIAlertView`. Just set the `UIActionSheet` delegate to self, and handle the user's tapping a button in the `UIActionSheet` delegate methods. It works like a charm, never experienced a problem.