# UIActionSheet not showing in popover

Tags: ios, ipad, uiactionsheet

I have a table view, and when the user selects a particular row, I want to display a simple action sheet to select if the new entry will come from an existing contact, or create a new contact.  I display the action sheet as such:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ( indexPath.row != 0  )
    {
        //Select the entry
    }
    else
    {
        UITableViewCell *selectedRow = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"New Contact", @"Existing Contact", nil];

        [sheet showFromRect:selectedRow.frame inView:tableView animated:YES];
        return;
    }

    //Do some other stuff...
```

}

According to the documentation...

> Discussion
>
> On iPad, this method displays the action sheet in a popover
>   whose arrow points to the specified rectangle of the view. The popover
>   does not overlap the specified rectangle.

And yet...the action sheet shows up at the bottom of my view, instead of a popover to the side.  The tableview is a master view in a splitviewcontroller

Any thoughts on why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and this answer help me:

[Using UIActionSheet on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078871/using-uiactionsheet-on-ipad?rq=1)

> *if you show it from a UIBarButtonItem or UIToolbar **that is already
>   inside a popover** it is then presented in a similar fashion as on the
>   iPhone*

The thing was for me that the table was showing int a split view and when on landscape that table was presented as a popover (lateral panel that you can hide with swipe), so once I turn the device to landscape the UIActionSheet starts showing in a popover. The reason is the one I put in bold: it cannot be show as a popover from inside another popover.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of popping from the tableView, try converting the cell bounds to the topmost view (the controller's and pop it from there...

```
CGRect frame = [self.view convertRect:cell.bounds fromView:cell];
[sheet showFromRect:frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Might be the case that there's more hierarchy inside the tableView and it's breaking your stuff.

Comment: Tried this: `CGRect frame = [selectedRow convertRect:selectedRow.frame toView:self.view];[sheet showFromRect:frame inView:self.view animated:YES];` to no avail though, same exact behavior